# How does the counter in TikZ \foreach work?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to partition a line segment into 5 segments of equal length and put tick marks at the new partition points.  I want the tick marks to appear in black.  Next I want to partition each new segment into 5 segments of equal length and want to color only the new tick marks in blue.

To achieve this task, I used TikZ and following is the code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,10)-- (15,10);
\foreach \x in {0,...,5}
\draw (3*\x,10)--(3*\x,9.8);
\foreach \x in {1,...,4,6,...,9,11,...,14,16,...,19,21,...,24}
\draw[draw=blue] (3*\x/5,10)--(3*\x/5,9.8);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, the outcome is not the desired outcome.

[image]

So I read the manual and it suggests that I should include at least two starting numbers.  I edited the code accordingly, and obtained the desired outcome.  The new code is given below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,10)-- (15,10);
\foreach \x in {0,...,5}
\draw (3*\x,10)--(3*\x,9.8);
\foreach \x in {1,...,4, 6,7,...,9, 11,12,...,14,16,17,...,19, 21,22,...,24}
\draw[draw=blue] (3*\x/5,10)--(3*\x/5,9.8);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is my puzzle.  If you give the starting number and the ending number to a counter that knows the increment is by 1(by default) then you do not have to give two starting numbers.

This seems to be the case,  as the following works.

```
\foreach \x in {0,...,5}
\draw (3*\x,10)--(3*\x,9.8);
```

But, the counter seems to loose this capability the second time around as I have to give two numbers to remind the counter that the increment is by 1.  (This is my hypothesis.)

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems that if you have the sequence `4,6,…,9`, how do you determine that the step size is one? From the `4,6` it appears that the step size might be 2. But once you add the second value, `4,6,7,…9` then from `7...9` the step size is determined to be one from the `6,7`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

By trial and error, it seems like whenever TikZ has an ambiguous step increment size, it simply assumes the <strike>previous integer</strike> current index minus one, as the step size. In other words, when you enter `{1,...4,6,...20}`, it gives you `{1,2,3,4,6,11,16}` with step size `6-1=5`and similarly if you enter `{1,...4,8.7,...25}` you get `{1,2,3,4,8.7, 16.4, 24.09999}` with step size `8.7-1=7.7`. You can test it for yourself using

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,...,4,8,...,25}
{\node at (\x / 2,0) {$\x$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It also applies to letters such that

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x [count = \xi] in {a,...,c,f,...,z}
{\node at (\xi,0) {$\x$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

results with `a,b,c,f,k,p,u,z`

Comment: Nice investigative work!  And I didn't know that the `...` syntax worked with letters.  Good to know.

Answer (score 10):

This is not an answer to your question but it's a way of drawing your black and blue ticks
with two `\foreach` help.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,10)-- (15,10);
\foreach \x in {0,...,4}{
    \draw (3*\x,10)--++(0,-0.2);
    \foreach \j in {1,...,4}
        \draw[draw=blue] ({3*(\x+\j/5)},10)--++(0,-0.2);
}
\draw (3*5,10)--++(0,-0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]